# Mysql Sum column of overlap dates between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A stores each stock amounts by days :

```
  +---+------------+----------+-------------+
  |id | Stock_id   | amount   |  Date       |
  +---+------------+----------+-------------+
  | 1 |          1 |      100 | 2017-09-05  |
  | 2 |          1 |      200 | 2017-09-06  |
  | 3 |          1 |      300 | 2017-09-07  |
  | 4 |          1 |      200 | 2017-09-08  |
  | 5 |          1 |      200 | 2017-09-09  |
  | 6 |          1 |      200 | 2017-09-10  |
  | 7 |          2 |      300 | 2017-09-06  |
  +---+------------+----------+-------------+
```

Table B contains relationship between stock id and category. Add date indicates when the stock was added to the category and remove date means the day which the stock was removed. if remove date is null , it means the stock is still in the category.

```
  +---+----------+  ------- +------------+------------+
  |id | Stock_id |Category  | Add Date   | Remove Date|
  +---+----------+--------  +------------+------------+
  | 1 |        1 | Category1| 2017-09-03 | 2017-09-07 |
  | 2 |        1 | Category1|2017-09-09  | null       |
  +---+----------+--------  +------------+------------+
```

My questions is give a time range, like from 2017-09-05 to 2017-09-08. first for the Stock1 and Category1, I want calculate the time overlap with table b, which is <2017-09-05 to 2017-09-06>. Then sum the amount in table A  from 2017-09-05 to 2017-09-06. the result is (100+200) = 300. if time range is 2017-09-06 to 2017-09-10, the overlap is <2017-09-06, 2017-09-09 to 2017-09-10>. sum result is (200+200+200)=600.

How can I do it?Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want want the amount of stock in each category for a given range of dates.  If so, this is a matter of joining the tables correctly and aggregating:

```
select a.stock_id, b.category, sum(a.amount)
from a join
     b
     on a.stock_id = b.stock_id and a.date >= a.add_date and 
        (a.date <= b.remove_date or b.remove_date is null)
where a.date >= '2017-09-05' and b.date <= '2017-09-08'
group by a.stock_id, b.category;
```